# for keyword 'this', is it the sender or the receiver of the message?

Tags: jquery, this

Given:

```
// attach newMessage to a prototype of object
object.prototype.newMessage
```

**(1)** is `object.prototype` **sending** newMessage *... or ...* **(2)** is newMessage **sent to** `object.prototype`; for example,

```
$.fn.newMessage = function() {
        var aObject = $(this);
}
```

Alternately, if `'this'` is used within the content of `newMessage`,
**(1)** is `'this'` the **sender** of `newMessage`  ... or ... **(2)** is `'this'` the **receiver** of `newMessage`

After many years with JavaScript, I firmly understood that the correct answer was **#1**.  However, since all objects are eventListeners, my inclination is **#2**.

**I still think** that the choice is **#1**, but I cannot shake the `eventListener` argument.

What concerns me is that the correct answer can be **either** #1 **or** #2, depending on other factors.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think the context of your problem is clear.... can you explain it with an example....

Comment: I still have some lingering doubt as to the correct answer. But, the more I think, the much more inclined I am to call 'this' an eventListener and, therefore, is the object to which the message is sent.